# C# 64-bit COM component for both 32-bit app and 64-bit Microsoft Excel VBA clients

Tags: c#, vba, delphi, 32bit-64bit, com-interop

I have created a COM DLL using C#.NET 4.6 and exported class does have all attributes to be exposed as a COM interface. It is built using x64 platform target and registered using "Register for COM interop" flag under project's build option. Inside Microsoft Excel's VBA 64-bit it can be consumed without any issues.

But, I also need to consume this same COM in a Delphi 7 app but Delphi 7 only accepts 32-bit COM references. This app can't be migrated to a more recent version of Delphi though so I need to make this COM component to also work with 32-bit clients.

If I build the same C# DLL targeting x86 platform, it will be visible and functional in Delphi 7 but will stop working in Microsoft Excel VBA 64-bit client.

I understood making a 32-bit client to work with a 64-bit COM server can be done using Surrogates and WOW registry entries but even following these guidelines ([Hosting a .NET DLL as an Out-Of-Process COM Server (EXE)](https://dzone.com/articles/hosting-net-dll-out-process)) to create extra Windows Registry entries in **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node** it doesn't work (I know this is an old post but thought it would still be valid).

I'm running a Windows 10 x64 machine. Am I missing any additional step? Any tips would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered re-implementing your COM server as an out-of-process EXE instead of an in-process DLL?

Comment: Hi @remy-lebeau, it must be a DLL because there are another clients in .NET and performance in these cases using an out-of-process COM server would be poor compared to direct .NET references which would be invalid if I turn this DLL into an EXE.

Comment: I've seen in many cases where a vendor supplies both a 32 bit and 64 bit dll and lets the user decide which one to use.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, yes, the question is how to make both 32/64 available at the same time in the same machine without having to create a second component. If I register first the 32-bit build of my DLL and then register the 64-bit version, windows registry will only recognize the latter.

Comment: You should be able to register both x86 and x64 DLL at the same time as there are two registries for COM. If you have issues with that, you should review your registration process.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you could try compiling for  'AnyCPU'

Comment: It is not possible.  Why do you think a company would distribute two version of a dll if they  could do it with only one.

Comment: @freeflow that's for pure .net libraries, but this is a native in process COM server

Comment: Yes, it sounds as though you are just registering this incorrectly. If you build 32 and 64 bit versions and register both, then the registry redirector will put all the entries in the appropriate places of the registry.

Comment: Ok, I would like to avoid having 2 DLLs to deploy once it seems possible to have 32-bit clients consuming 64-bit COM DLLs if you use surrogates to trick clients.

Answer (score 0):

It seems "AnyCPU" does the trick when you UNcheck "Register for COM Interop" in project settings.

To register it on user's machine, I'm running this with Admin rights:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /tlb /codebase "C:\MyCOM.dll"

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /tlb /codebase "C:\MyCOM.dll"
```

Then, to remove (also as Admin):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "C:\MyCOM.dll" /u

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "C:\MyCOM.dll" /u
```

But, it seems some entries are left behind in registry.

Isn't "/u" enough for unregistering it?

Thank you.